# Error when signing a Xamarin UWP msixbundle

Tags: code-signing, xamarin.uwp

I am trying to sign a Xamarin app so that i can sideload it on PCs in my network.
I can sign the exe,but am unable to sign the msixbundle. I get the following error:
ignTool Error: An unexpected internal error has occurred.
Error information: "Error: SignerSign() failed." (-2147024885/0x8007000b)

i cannot find any info on this...
any ideas out there?